# Unexpected web page refresh in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I've been facing this weird behavior for a while now and can't find any workaround.

There is a button with certain methods called on click.
In Firefox works well. In Chrome it just refreshes the whole page.

```js
$("#modoComparativa").click(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass("active")){
                $('#histFromDate').attr("placeholder","Date 1");
                $('#histToDate').attr("disabled","disabled").attr("placeholder","Date 2");
                startDatepickerComp();
            }
            else{
                $('#histFromDate').attr("placeholder","Initial date");
                $('#histToDate').attr("disabled","disabled").attr("placeholder","Final date");
                startDatepicker();
            }
            $('#clearDates').attr("disabled","disabled");
            // This function calls another function causing the odd behavior in Chrome
            requestGraph(idDetail, idArea, "", "");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If I comment out everything but the selector and the call to the click method, the behavior is the same. It refreshes everything.

I can't figure out how to debug this as each time I press the button, the whole page refreshes and no log/errors remains in the browser debugger.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Edit - Addition of the selector as requested:

```
<div class="form-group"><button class="tooltip3 btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-random" id="modoComparativa" data-toggle="tooltip" title="ACTIVAR COMPARATIVAS" data-placement="bottom"></button>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the markup for the `#modoComparativa` element?  Also, in chrome, you can click the "Preserve log" checkbox above the console and it will not clear when the page refreshes.

Comment: Added as an edit. Will try the Preserve log feature, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a return false to your click callback to prevent actions due to your html syntax (like form submission or clicking on a anchor tag).

```
$("#modoComparativa").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // your existing code
}
```

Edit: Since you added your html...

If your button is within a form, you can also add the type="button" attribute to prevent it from submitting your form.

```
<button type="button" class="tooltip3 btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-random" id="modoComparativa" data-toggle="tooltip" title="ACTIVAR COMPARATIVAS" data-placement="bottom"></button>
```

Thank you to lonesomeday for suggesting http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Genius! It's working as expected now. Much appreciated.

Comment: Still have to wait 5 minutes to accept this super fast and accurate answer.

Comment: `return false` is not the ideal way to do this. The correct way is `event.preventDefault()`, preferably at the top of the callback function.

Comment: Great advice, could you please explain why?

Comment: @lenord The problem with `return false` is that there can be code that gets executed _before_ the return statement. If an exception occurs (or someone not familiar with the implications of the "false" adds a `return;`) in your code before you reach the return, the page will refresh.

Comment: This is very interesting. Although we were unable to repeat this error again I will consider this topic in the next sprint. Thanks for the heads up (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I added an answer which could be useful for people stumbling here but having other causes for this behavior.
This kind of unexpected random reload can be due to several causes:

- As stated in other answers a link which propagates the click and then performs a `GET` on the page itself
- An image tag `<img>` where the `src` is empty or invalid, the browser will attempt to load the image using `GET`, but will in fact refresh the page instead (empty = relative to the page = page). Even a hidden image will be loaded, so this can be tricky to find, use the browser console !
- Some javascript logic which refreshes the page programmatically in some conditions (session expired, token expired ...)
- A browser 'feature', for example: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1204335, or https://superuser.com/questions/1048029/disable-auto-refresh-tabs-in-chrome-desktop

In any case use the browser console and look for suspect `GET` calls to the page itself or redirects.